# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Boot Problems

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel, intel, bios

for some time now (couple of months) i keep having boot problems with Ubuntu on my laptop. I had a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu. In the beginning everything was running fine, no problems at all. After some time i noticed that i couldn't boot into Ubuntu reliably. I figured it was because of the dual boot and because i wasn't using Windows much anyway i decided to just switch to Ubuntu once and for all.

But the problem didn't go away even with a clean install and Ubuntu as my only OS. Here is whats happening:

In the beginning there were some times where Ubuntu just wouldn't boot. After the normal Lenovo BIOS screen, the screen just stayed black with the backlight turned on. At first it seemed like this only happened when my laptop wasn't connected to power. Since then I've tried to reliably reproduce the problem but it seemed like its just random.

Now it never boots normally at all. Turn it on, black screen -> restart -> grub, select recovery mode, boot into it -> restart. Only through recovery mode restart I'm able to boot normally, and even this seems to not work reliably... I just can't figure out where the problem is and I'm getting more desperate every day... I have a ton of Uni work so i cant troubleshoot for hours every day but i gathered some info, so please if anyone has a idea what i could try, help would be very much appreciated.

From what info I've gathered i suspect its a video card driver problem maybe caused by the BIOS.
Here are my specs:

**Lenovo L460**

- Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
- 8 GB Ram
- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 64-Bit
- Gnome Version 3.36.8
- Window System X11
- Kernel            : Linux 5.8.0-38-generic (x86_64)
- Version       : #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 6 10:15:55 UTC 2021
- C Library     : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) 2.31
- display
  description: VGA compatible controller
  product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 2
  bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
  version: 07
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
  configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
  resources: irq:128 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

**Grub:**

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
```

```
dmesg -l err -T
[Mo Jän 18 11:42:41 2021] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0xb2 (or later)
[Mo Jän 18 11:42:41 2021] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[Mo Jän 18 11:42:41 2021] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[Mo Jän 18 11:42:41 2021] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[Mo Jän 18 11:42:41 2021] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[Mo Jän 18 11:42:42 2021] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[Mo Jän 18 11:42:42 2021] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[Mo Jän 18 11:42:42 2021] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[Mo Jän 18 11:42:42 2021] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
[Mo Jän 18 11:42:46 2021] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware header (-38)
[Mo Jän 18 11:43:47 2021] hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: Unable to bind the codec
```

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: LENOVO
    Version: R08ET31W (1.05 )
    Release Date: 12/25/2015
    Address: 0xE0000
    Runtime Size: 128 kB
    ROM Size: 16 MB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        PNP is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        EDD is supported
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 1.5
    Firmware Revision: 1.5

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 20FU001LGE
    Version: ThinkPad L460
    Serial Number: PF0GLKVC
    UUID: e3a3664c-354b-11b2-a85c-a1da8458b640
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_20FU_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad L460
    Family: ThinkPad L460

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 20FU001LGE
    Version: SDK0J40705 WIN
    Serial Number: L1HF61S00YY
    Asset Tag: Not Available
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Not Available
    Chassis Handle: 0x0000
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 24, 5 bytes
Hardware Security
    Power-On Password Status: Disabled
    Keyboard Password Status: Not Implemented
    Administrator Password Status: Disabled
    Front Panel Reset Status: Not Implemented
```

```
intel-microcode is already the newest version (3.20201110.0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
```

```
dmesg | grep microcode
[    0.046921] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0xb2 (or later)
[    0.183641] SRBDS: Vulnerable: No microcode
[    0.183749] MDS: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode
```

If I should provide some more Information please let me know. FYI I'm relatively new to GNU/Linux

My next step will be trying to update the BIOS.

Comment: Update: Ofc after i asked the question it was working for some time. Altough now it happened again. But after a ```apt-get upgrade``` i got this message:

```I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5
I: (UUID=957871e1-58bc-4f5b-ba3d-009ed0deb33d)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.```

Comment: OK so some new news: this seems to happen most of the time when my laptop isn't connected to power and runs of the battery. I would say then it happens in like 90% of the time.

Comment: I'm having lots of boot issues, have dual monitor, so video drivers could be a cause. Every time canonical rolls a release, system goes broken. No final solution until now...